# Is there any exceptions to be avoided in this simple class?

Tags: java, exception

This is from a practice exam, anyhow, I was thinking, what are the exception that I should take care of?

[image: screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think obvious runtime exceptions mean here NullPointerException, ArrayOutOFBoundsException, IllegalArgumentException and so on, so your code will run without obvious failures.

Answer (score 1):

The first one that comes to mind is `NullPointerException` if you're doing anything with the name.  For instance, if Employee's or SessionalEmployee's toString() were do anything with the name other than displaying it...